# IO pin for iCE40 Ultra

Tags: fpga, pins, io

What is the maximum IO pin current (for regular pins, not for LED pins) for iCE40 Ultra FPGA?

Comment: This information can be found in the datasheet, have you read the whole thing? Because you should read the datasheet before you design with a device.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking members to read the datasheet for you is not really electronic design

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See page 25 of this document: http://www.latticesemi.com/view_document?document_id=50666

8 mA for LVCMOS 3.3, 6 mA for LVCMOS 2.5, and 4 mA for LVCMOS 1.8.

Comment: Now page 32, table 4.15.

Comment: Strangely, though, the IBIS model for pin 26 output (from Lattice) is driving between 36mA to 43mA ("min" to "max" model). Which to believe, the IBIS model or the datasheet? a factor of 4x difference.

Comment: Perhaps the allowed DC current draw is much lower than pulse capability of the output driver, for AC output waveforms.